What is the workaround or solution for Invalid object reference: LiveChatTranscript if chat settings are scheduled for retirement?
Trying to setup an Einstein-Bot in my test org, (chose the Standard-Bot and the Intro Template) and at the last one of the setting-up steps, I get an error: "Invalid object reference: LiveChatTranscript".
Looking up a solution it seems to be that enabling the "Enable Chat" checkbox in chat settings, is the solution.
But when going to chat settings page to do that, there is a message about:
"Legacy chat is being retired on February 14, 2026, and is in maintenance mode until then",
and I'm suggested to: "migrate to Messaging for In-App and Web before that date, to avoid service interruptions."
What do I do now - instead of that? how do I complete the bot set-up?
what is a different way to be able to enable chat, or a substitute of it?

Refer to this:
Chat & Live Agent Retirement: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001790618&type=1
Considerations when Replacing Chat with Messaging for In-App and Web: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.miaw_replacing_chat_considerations.htm&type=5

I've already done that, that link appears in the message that notifies about the scheduled retirement and unavailability.
Id like a more specific answer from someone who already got passed that step, and built an Einstein-bot recently and can tell me exactly what to do.

Plan for Messaging for In-App and Web and Set Up Messaging for In-App and Web
